# Create a "Web Optimized" PDF using PoDoFo

Tags: c++, pdf, podofo

I can create a PDF in my C++ app using `PdfStreamedDocument` object with no issue. I can also see that it has a function to check and see if the document is Linearized (web optimized). But I cannot find how to force the document that I'm creating to be web optimized (there is no *SetLinearized* function).
So how can I force the document that I'm creating Using `CreatePage` and draw text and image into each page useing `PoDoFo::PdfPainter` to be "web optimized" (`IsLinearized` should return true)?
Thank you

Comment: AFAIK `IsLinearized()` isnt even a method anymore